# I want to count total product on a amazon page using python and selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am trying to count total product on an amazon page i.e. "https://www.amazon.com/s?k=irobot+roomba" using python and selenium.

I have facing problems with these two lines

```
list_product_on_page=browser.find_element_by_xpath('//[@id="search"]/div[1]/div[2]/div/span[3]/div[2]/div') 
list_product_on_page.size
```

This is what I tried..
[image]
I want to count total product in this single page.

[image]

this is the code I tried so far

Comment: Please do not post your code as an image. Also do not post error messages as an image. Use text instead

Answer (score 0):

To print the count of the products you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `css_selector`:

  ```
  print(len(driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.a-section img[src^='https://m.media-amazon.com/images']")))
  ```
- Using `xpath`:

  ```
  print(len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'a-section')]//img[starts-with(@src, 'https://m.media-amazon.com/images')]")))
  ```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to count products on page you can do:

```
list_product_on_page = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.s-result-item.s-asin') 
print(len(list_product_on_page))
```